# Why does my facebook app posts are not showing on my friends stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My application after being granted with 'publish_actions' authorization is posting content to a user's wall but the user's friends are not seeing the post.

my app is authorized by facebook on the app review section 
with this status "Approved: publish_actions"

my javascript post format and action:

```
 FB.login(function () {
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
                message: contents.description,
                link: link + '?context=' + new Date().getTime(),
                picture: imageURL,
                name: some text,
                caption: contents.caption,
                description: contents.defaultDescription
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    console.error(response.error.message)
                }
                console.log(response)
            });
        }, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
```

Comment: Is your app set live? (App Dashboard)

Comment: Yes, the app is live and not in sandbox.

Comment: Do the friends just not see the post in their newsfeed, or not even on the posting user’s timeline? Go check under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications what privacy level is set for content published by the app.

Comment: They see it on the user's timeline and only once in awhile they see it in the news feed usualy even if they change the news feed setting to show recent storys they don't see the post

Comment: If they can see it on the user’s timeline, then everything went fine. Newsfeed distribution depends on multiple factors, and is nothing you can influence directly. If f.e. you published a lot of test posts recently, that might be one factor that gets you less distribution at the moment.